# Bounds for distance of two samples inpendently drawn from a distribution with fixed variance

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid from an arbitrary distribution with variance $\sigma^2$. How can we derive an upper bound for:
$$P(|X_1-X_2|\ge\delta)$$

One simple idea is Chebyshev's Inequality, however, when $\delta<\sqrt{2}\sigma$, we have
$$P(|X_1-X_2|\ge\delta)\le\frac{var(X_1-X_2)}{\delta^2}=\frac{2\sigma^2}{\delta^2},$$
which literally tells nothing. Clearly, this inequality can be improved in this case.

How can we get a better bound? Thank you.

Comment: Chebychev's inequality is sharp. I think it is possible that the distribution of $X_1$ can be chosen such that $X_1 - X_2$ is [this distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Sharpness_of_bounds), in which case the inequality cannot be improved. (I haven't checked though.)

Comment: Hi angryavian. Yes, indeed Chebychev's inequality is sharp in the general case. You have provided a case that Chebychev's inequality can not be improved. However, the case is that it's impossible for $X_1-X_2$ following that distribution. That's why we can improve the result.

Comment: If you don't know anything else about these r.v.'s (e.g. about higher moments) it is very hard to improve on Chebyshev.  The only piece of information that I see not being used here is that $X_1-X_2$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

If $2X_1 \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$ then $X_1 - X_2$ takes values $-1,0,1$ with probabilities $p(1-p), p^2 + (1-p)^2, p(1-p)$.
Then we have $P(|X_1 - X_2| \ge 1) = 2p(1-p)$ which is precisely the Chebychev bound. Scaling this example will give you a similar example for a different choice of $\delta$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In your example, $1=\delta^2\ge4\sigma^2=4p(1-p)$. In this case, the Chebychev bound is sharp. However, when $\delta^2<2\sigma^2$, obviously the Chebychev bound is not sharp since $P(|X_1-X_2|\ge\delta)<1<\frac{2\sigma^2}{\delta^2}$.